# Непонятная битовая операция

Tags: c++, c, битовые-операции

Что может означать операция `i = i & (i+1)` в реализации дерева отрезков?

Comment: Что конкретно она означает без контекста с кодом не понять скорее всего. Приведите пример.

Comment: Более того, я так понимаю, что речь идёт не о дереве отрезков, а о дереве Фенвика. Я прав?  http://e-maxx.ru/algo/fenwick_tree

Answer (score 6):

Превращает все завершающие единичные биты в нулевые; если таковых нет - просто возвращает исходное значение.

```
i         0011011111  00101100100  11010101000
i+1       0011100000  00101100101  11010101001

i&(i+1)   0011000000  00101100100  11010101000
```

Для чего именно это сделано в конкретной программе - это уж смотрите, где и как это действие использовано...